# Unwanted Char Appears

Tags: c#, calculator

I am beginner , am trying to create a calculator. the way of the code working is there is a method for summing and one for subtraction ETC.
when i call the subtraction method unwanted minus appears before the answer in the textbox ( i know my code could be using harder way to do the same purpose but i am just beginner trying to do some code )

```
double rat;
byte operations; 

public void TheEqualMinus(double earlier) //Substraction Operation Method
{
     double _minus;
     _minus = Convert.ToDouble(result.Text);

    double last = _minus - earlier;
    result.Text = last.ToString();
}

private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //The Subtract Button
    operations = 2;
    rat = Convert.ToDouble(result.Text);
    label1.Text = rat + " -";
    result.Text = "";
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // equal button
    NewText = true; //boolean to newtext
    switch (operations)
    {
        case (1):   //addition 
            TheEqualSum(rat);
            label1.Text = "";
            break;
        case (2):   //substraction
            TheEqualMinus(rat);
            label1.Text = "";
            break;
    }
}
```

and the answer output becomes " -  The Correct Answer i want  "
ex. 9-6 = -3
so any ideas how to remove this minus ?

Comment: Is your text including the minus sign? If you input text -3 the parser will assume you meant "negative 3"

Comment: Is you `minus` value 6 and your `earlier` value 9?

Comment: Why don't you name the buttons accordingly instead of using comments like `//The Subtract Button`? It will make your code much easier to understand. Of course, do that also with labels, textboxex, etc. Also, use an `enum` for the operations instead of numbers, so you could do `case Operations.Addition:`, etc. In any case, you don't need parenthesis there (`case 1:` would be enough).

Comment: Like @LarsTech said, you are doing `result.Text - earlier`, which seems to be 6 - 9.

Comment: @Andrew ahhhhh i should have typed earlier - _Minus That was the problem, Thank you

Comment: @Andrew thank you for the tips i will do it next time :D, operations is because when i click any button after the equal button i want to make sure that the textbox is cleaned. so in case i clicked equal button clean the button , and if not don't clean it

Comment: You can still do that and use an `enum` for the switch instead of a number, which is meaningless. If you need comments to make your code understandable, it's probably not good code. Your code seems to have many bad practices. You may want to publish it here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments above, this was fixed by simply changing this:

```
double last = _minus - earlier;
```

to this:

```
double last = earlier - _minus;
```